# Netlify deploy can't fetch API to Heroku backend

Tags: heroku, proxy, fetch-api, netlify

Netlify frontend can't fetch API from Heroku backend.
The Request URL adddress below is definitly not correct. How to make it correct?

In dev tool it shows this:
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/api/castles

package.json frontend:"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/",

This is the link of Netlify:
https://trusting-ride-8e237a.netlify.app/
Frontend code link :
https://github.com/ZhiJuanTang/Castle_Frontend

This is the link of Heroku:
https://castlebackend.herokuapp.com/api/castles
Backernd code link:
https://github.com/ZhiJuanTang/Castle_Backend

Answer (score 0):

The frontend code relies on an environment variable to define the API endpoint:

```js
const res = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BLOG_API}/api/castles`);
```

Did you define REACT_APP_BLOG_API as an environment variable in Netlify? See [Netlify Integration](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/create-react-app/#netlify-integration) in the documentation.